# Adobe Air integrar Flex Componets

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-flex, adobe-air

Eu estou a desenvolver um projecto através do Adobe AIR e Action-Script 3, deparei que as UI Components não tem suporte para mobile, ou seja em Android ou iOS eles não fazem scroll-bar para baixo e para cima com o dedo.

Pelo que percebo, que tem essa funcionalidade é a Framework Flex. é possivel integrar os componentes Flex para o projecto actual que está em AIR? Se sim, como?

Tecnologias:

Adobe Flash Profissional CC 2015
Adobe Flash Builder 4.7
Adobe AIR 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não conseguirá utilizar as bibliotecas do Flex no AIR AS3 [por possuírem SDKs e compiladores diferentes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12555280/2456028). O Flex SDK é *quase* uma extensão do AIR SDK, mas não totalmente compatível pois existem estruturas de pastas e arquivos de projetos distintos.

O que você pode fazer é *converter* sua aplicação. Esse processo envolve a migração de bibliotecas, objetos visuais e estrutura de pastas, o que torna muito trabalhoso de fazer.

Você pode utilizar algumas bibliotecas de componentes de terceiros ou criar os seus próprios componentes. O código a seguir tem um exemplo bem básico de *scrolling*:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.GradientType;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight * 2);
mc.graphics.endFill();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
mc.graphics.drawCircle(stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight, 50);
mc.graphics.endFill();

this.addChild(mc);

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

mc.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchBegin);
mc.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);

function touchBegin(e:TouchEvent):void {
    mc.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID, false, new Rectangle(0, - stage.stageHeight, 0, stage.stageHeight * 2));
}

function touchEnd(e:TouchEvent):void {
    mc.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}
```

Há outros tutoriais na internet para você realizar o scroll de objetos. Uma boa biblioteca para você incrementar com efeitos de *smoothing* é o [Greensock](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/4928-how-to-drag-scroll-a-moiveclip-in-a-smooth-way/).